# How to construct a pdf of a copula with a t distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability-density

My question: To fit some data i have used a copula with a t-distribution. With that copula i made an scatter density plot of n samples. The result, knowing my data, was satisfying.

Performed with the following script:

```
U=ksdensity(Udata1,Udata1,'function','cdf'); % Transforming the data to copula scale(Unit Square) 
R=ksdensity(Rdata1,Rdata1,'function','cdf');
[Rho,nu]=copulafit('t',[U R],'method','ApproximateML')
r=copularnd('t',Rho,nu,100000) % Generates n samples from the copula
Uc=r(:,1);
Rc=r(:,2);
U2=ksdensity(Udata1,Uc,'function','icdf'); % Transforming the data back to the original scale
R2=ksdensity(Rdata1,Rc,'function','icdf');
out = scatplot(U2,R2,'squares',2,40,5,1,5)
```

Furthermore i wanted to make a pdf of the copula. With the script below:

```
U=ksdensity(Udata1:,Udata1,'function','cdf'); 
R=ksdensity(Rdata1,Rdata1,'function','cdf');
[Rho,nu]=copulafit('t',[U R],'method','ApproximateML')
x1 = -2:.2:4; x2 = -10:.2:10;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvtpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],Rho,nu);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
axis([-2 4 -10 10 0 .2])
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); zlabel('Probability Density');
```

The result was not satisfying because it doesnt seem to match with my earlier scatter plot:

I think i am missing some rescaling when i construct the pdf, but i am not sure. And dont know how to perform or use this rescaling.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you look at the [`copulapdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulapdf.html?refresh=true) function?

Comment: Well i tried this:

    [U1,U2] = meshgrid(Udata1,Rdata1);
    U=ksdensity(Udata1,Udata1,'function','cdf'); % Transforming the data to copula scale(Unit Square) 
    R=ksdensity(Rdata1,Rdata1,'function','cdf');
    [Rho,nu]=copulafit('t',[U R],'method','ApproximateML') 
    f = copulapdf('t',[U1(:) U2(:)],Rho,nu);
    f = reshape(f,size(U1));
    figure()
    surf(U1,U2,log(f),'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none')
    view([-15,20])

But then i got the following error:
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in copulapdf (line 52)out(~isnan(out)) = 0.5;